# What is the purpose of the second (identical) line in these macro / command declarations?

Tags: macros

*[Disclaimer: though I have been using LaTeX for quite some time, I still have a lot to learn about the code and customisation]*

In the process of writing my Master Thesis, I picked up [this template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/graduate-thesis). It has commands for the name of the university / department, and so on in a `*.cls` file like this:

```
\department  {\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {Department or School Name}}
                {Department or School Name}}
\DEPARTMENT  {\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\group       {\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {Research Group Name}}
                {Research Group Name}}
\GROUP       {\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\faculty     {\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {Faculty Name}}
                {Faculty Name}}
\FACULTY     {\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
```

And they are declared as follows:

```
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\deptname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\DEPARTMENT}[1]{\def\DEPTNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\group}[1]{\def\groupname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\GROUP}[1]{\def\GROUPNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\FACULTY}[1]{\def\FACNAME{#1}}
```

What is the purpose of the second identical line of text in the template? It seems by only changing the top one it already shows correctly. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's pick one of your command calls (just splitted):

```
\DEPARTMENT  {
    \texorpdfstring{
        \href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
             {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}
    }
    {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}
}
```

That means that you define your `\DEPTNAME` to behave different in the output and, f.i., bookmarks. In the output you'll find a hyperlink which will appear like the first argument in all caps.

If there's no hyperlink generated (e.g. in bookmarks) you'll get the second all caps string. Why you do have to give those identical definitions is unclear to me, but it's a design decision.

Comment: Oh gosh! I totally read over the fact that `\texorpdfstring` takes two arguments! Probably partly because I expect a function that takes multiple parameters to be declared more like `function(foo, bar)` instead of `function{foo}{bar}`. Thanks!

So the `texorpdfstring` just enables to return a different string for parsing in places where more complex mathy stuff and such is not supported?

Comment: @Phantom Well, that's the purpose of `\texorpdfstring`.

Comment: I did not know what the function did (or how) before now. Thanks!